# Conditional insert in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, python-3.7

I am creating a leave tracker app where I want to store the user ID along with the from date and to date. I am using Amazon's DynamoDB as the database, and the user enters a leave through a custom command.
Eg: **apply-leave** from-date to-date

I want to avoid duplicate entries in the database. For example, if a user has already applied for a leave between 06-10-2019 to 10-10-2019 and applies for a leave between the same dates again, they should get a message saying that this already exists and a new record should not be created for the same.

However, a user can apply for multiple leaves and two users can take a leave between the same dates.

I tried using a conditional statement as follows:

```py
table.put_item(
            Item={
                'leave_id': leave_id,
                'user_id': user_id,
                'from_date': from_date,
                'to_date': to_date,
            },
            ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(user_id) AND attribute_not_exists(from_date) AND attribute_not_exists(to_date)'
        )
```

where leave_id is the partition key. However, this does not work and a new row is added every time, even if it is the same dates. I have looked through similar other questions, but haven't been able to understand how to get this configured correctly.

Any ideas on how I should go about this, or if there is a different design that I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling your code with the `leave_id` that **doesn't** yet exist in the table, the item will always be inserted. If you call your code with `leave_id` that **does** already exist in your table you should be getting `An error occurred (ConditionalCheckFailedException) when calling the PutItem operation: The conditional request failed` error message.

I have two suggestions:

If you don't want to change your table, you can create a secondary index with `user_id` as the partition key and then query the index for all the items where the given user has some `from_date` and `to_date` attributes. 
Like this:

```
table.query(
    IndexName='user_id-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('user_id').eq(user_id),
    FilterExpression=Attr('from_date').exists() & Attr('from_date').exists()
)
```

Then you will need to check for overlapping leave requests, etc. (eg. leave request that starts before the one that is already in place finishes). After deciding that the leave request is a valid one you will call `put_item`.

Another suggestion and probably a better one would be to create a composite primary key on your table with `user_id` as a partition key and `leave_id` as a sort key. That way you could execute a query for all leave requests from a particular user without the need to create a secondary index.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! leave_id is a random uuid to uniquely identify each row. So not sure how this can be used as a sort key, as it is unique for every row.

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem, the point was to be able to query the table for all leave requests for a particular user. You can always try my first suggestion with an index if you can't/don't want to change how your table is defined.